# Using "Channels" and "Buffer" in NIO

Tags: java, sockets, buffer, nio

I have this following example from my text book:

```
 1 import java.nio.*;
 2 import java.nio.channels.*;
 3 import java.net.*;
 4 import java.io.IOException;
 5 
 6 public class ChargenClient {
 7 
 8   public static int DEFAULT_PORT = 19;
 9 
10   public static void main(String[] args) {
11 
12     if (args.length == 0) {
13       System.out.println("Usage: java ChargenClient host [port]");
14       return;
15     }
16 
17     int port;
18     try {
19       port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
20     } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
21       port = DEFAULT_PORT;
22     }
23 
24     try {
25       SocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(args[0], port);
26       SocketChannel client = SocketChannel.open(address);
27 
28       ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(74);
29       WritableByteChannel out = Channels.newChannel(System.out);
30 
31       while (client.read(buffer) != -1) {
32         buffer.flip();
33         out.write(buffer);
34         buffer.clear();
35       }
36     } catch (IOException ex) {
37       ex.printStackTrace();
38     }
39   }
40 }
```

It makes use of `Channels` class from NIO Java package on line #29.

1. I want to know how does using this class gains performance? Will it be slower if I had simply used `System.out.println`?
2. Is using `ByteBuffer` class faster than using Streams or just optional? It may be convenience to use `flip()` and `rewind()` but if I want to say just `write()` to socket without a buffer can I still do that? The reason I am confused because I've read NIO is Buffer-Oriented and not Stream Oriented.

Comment: 1. This code reads. `System.out.println()` writes. Comparing their speeds is meaningless. 2. It's optional.

Comment: @EJP: Why NIO doesn't provide Stream methods like getOutputStream as with IO sockets but rather it has read and write only for buffers?

Comment: Because channels are not stream-oriented, as you said yourself, and because the stream API isn't useful for channels: for example, `write()` doesn't return a count, which is required in non-blocking modde.